# Conversion from aware datetime to timestamp and back is gaining one hour?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, epoch, date-conversion

I always get confused with `datetimes` and timezone conversion in Python, but now I'm experiencing a rather odd behavior. I suspect (strongly) that this is related to Daylight Saving Times, but I don't know for sure, and I definitely don't know how to handle it correctly.

Here's what happens: If I make a `datetime` instance aware of its timezone, I create an `epoch` UTC timestamp from it, and I re-create a `datetime` instance back from that timestamp, I seem to be gaining one hour:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>>
>>> naive = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print "Naive 'now' %s" % naive
Naive 'now' 2014-08-21 11:19:13.019046

>>> eastern_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> now_eastern = eastern_tz.localize(naive)
>>> print "Now (eastern) is %s" % now_eastern
Now (eastern) is 2014-08-21 11:19:13.019046-04:00

>>> print "Now (utc) is %s" % now_eastern.astimezone(pytz.utc)
Now (utc) is 2014-08-21 15:19:13.019046+00:00
# This one is correct

>>> now_eastern_utc_timetuple = now_eastern.utctimetuple()
>>> print "Now (eastern) as timetuple %s" % now_eastern_utc_timetuple
Now (eastern) as timetuple time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=21, \
                   tm_hour=15, tm_min=19, tm_sec=13, tm_wday=3, \
                   tm_yday=233, tm_isdst=0)
# Shouldn't this be isdst=1 ? ----------^^^

>>> now_epoch = time.mktime(now_eastern_utc_timetuple)
>>> print "now epoch (UTC) %s" % now_epoch
now epoch (UTC) 1408652353.0
# I'm pretty sure this is +3600 in advance 

>>> print "Converted back: %s" % datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now_epoch)
Converted back: 2014-08-21 16:19:13
```

I've verified the times using [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/), and I'm pretty sure the timestamp generated from the `utctimetuple` is adding one hour. As I mentioned, I'm almost certain that this is related to Daylight Time Saving unawareness, because if I try with a date when the daylight time savings is not in use (for instance, December), it works fine.

```
>>> naive = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012/12/12 10:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
>>> print "Naive 'now' %s" % naive
Naive 'now' 2012-12-12 10:00:00

>>> eastern_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> now_eastern = eastern_tz.localize(naive)
>>> print "Now (eastern) is %s" % now_eastern
Now (eastern) is 2012-12-12 10:00:00-05:00

>>> print "Now (utc) is %s" % now_eastern.astimezone(pytz.utc)
Now (utc) is 2012-12-12 15:00:00+00:00

>>> now_eastern_utc_timetuple = now_eastern.utctimetuple()
>>> print "Now (eastern) as timetuple %s" % now_eastern_utc_timetuple
Now (eastern) as timetuple time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=12,\
                   tm_hour=15, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, \
                   tm_yday=347, tm_isdst=0)

>>> now_epoch = time.mktime(now_eastern_utc_timetuple)
>>> print "now epoch (UTC) %s" % now_epoch
now epoch (UTC) 1355342400.0

>>> print "Converted back: %s" % datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now_epoch)
Converted back: 2012-12-12 15:00:00
```

I'm using:

- Mac Os X 10.9.4
- Python 2.7
- pytz 2012j

So the question is: How can I handle this kind of conversion correctly? Is this issue related to DST?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't this be isdst=1 ?

No. You ask an aware datetime object to give you a UTC time tuple. UTC has no DST therefore `tm_isdst` is *always* zero.

`now_eastern.astimezone(pytz.utc)` and `now_eastern.utctimetuple()` produce the same time. They are correct if `now_eastern` is correct.

`time.mktime(now_eastern_utc_timetuple)` is **incorrect** because `mktime()` expects local time but `now_eastern_utc_timetuple` is in UTC. You could use `calendar.timegm(now_eastern_utc_timetuple)` instead or better `now_eastern.timestamp()`, see [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279).

I would use: `now_eastern = eastern_tz.localize(naive, is_dst=None)` (*assuming `naive` represents time in `'US/Eastern'` i.e., assuming your local timezone is `'US/Eastern'`*, you could use `tzlocal.get_localzone()` to get the local timezone automatically) <- raise an exception instead of returning a wrong answer or better: `now_eastern = datetime.now(eastern)`.